# Apollo GraphQl react. How to clear query cache for all variable combinations?

Tags: caching, react-apollo

I am using apollo graphql in my react application.
Say I have the following query:

```
query ListQuery($filter: String!) {
   items(filter: $filter) {
     id
     name
   }
}
```

This query lets me query a list of items using a filter. Say I used filter string A, and then used filter string B. The cache would now contain two entries: ListQuery(A) and ListQuery(B).

Now let's say I use a mutation to add a new item. How can I remove all the cached queries from the cache? So in this case, I want to remove both ListQuery(A) and ListQuery(B) from the cache.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you actually want to remove the cached queries? Typically one would update them with a refetch.

Comment: Looks like a feature request:https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/29 or https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/4

Answer (score 12):

In your case, you can use the apollo's method
client.resetStore();

It will clear the previous cache and then load the active queries.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 query ListQuery($filter: String!) {
       items(filter: $filter) {
         id
         name
       }
    },
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
```

More here:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#bypassing-the-cache

Comment: You can improve on this by still caching the main `ListQuery` query without a `filter`.

Answer (score 3):

Try evicting the particular query object from the cache...

```
cache.evict({ id: "ROOT_QUERY", fieldName: "listQuery" });
cache.gc();
```

I got this working after reading this: https://danreynolds.ca/tech/2020/05/04/Apollo-3-Client-Cache/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you need is [`refetchQueries`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo#graphql-mutation-options-refetchQueries) option/prop to be set to array of query names strings. The documentation states that:

> If options.refetchQueries is an array of strings then Apollo Client
> will look for any queries with the same names as the provided strings
> and will refetch those queries with their current variables.

So as an example for using `graphql` HOC you could try to do:

```
function SomeComponent(props) {

  const performMutation = () => {
    props.doStuff({ refetchQueries: ["ListQuery"] })
      .then(/* ... */)
      .catch(/* ... */)
  }

  return (/* ... */)
}

export default graphql(DO_STUFF, { name: "doStuff" })(SomeComponent)
```

Or with the `Mutation` component:

```
function SomeComponent(props) {
  return (
    <Mutation
      mutation={DO_STUFF}
      refetchQueries={mutationResult => ["ListQuery"]}>
      {(doStuff, { loading, error }) => {
        /* ... */
      }}
    </Mutation>
  );
}
```

If this is somehow doesn't do what you need, there is also a [workaround using `update` option](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/4#issuecomment-431119231).

Comment: Refetch sometimes doesn't clear cache, there is a bug https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6925#issuecomment-684104444

Comment: Agree with what @AleksandrSmyshliaev said above. There are currently known issues with refetchQueries. See here for a nice explanation... https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/5419#issuecomment-1242511457 

See also here for a discussion on how to evict such a set of queries that the OP is looking to do https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6795

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by first changing a value in my schema from required to not required, which resulted in values being queried again! After that, I reverted the change and have had no problems!

Answer (score -5):

Read about fetch policies
[options.fetchPolicy](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-config-options-fetchPolicy)

--Edit:--

But it is only as a trick if you want reset only one query. To reset all store see answer by @Nitin : Set *fetchPolicy* to **network-only**. Refresh query. Return it to option of your choice.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: This answer is not very helpful and also I think fetchPolicy and clearing the cache are two different things.

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu I agree. `fetchPolicy` determines how the query interacts with the cache store. For instance `fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'` will lookup the cache first *and* call the server. Read more about fetchPolicy here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#setting-a-fetch-policy